# Step Line with missing points - Live charts

Tags: c#, livecharts

There is way to create chart with missing points for StepLineSeries?

There is sample for LineSeries https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Missing%20Points

but set double.NaN value for StepLineSeries throw error:

> NaN "is an invalid value for property" Y1 ". '

Sample from link:

```
    public MissingPointsExample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Series = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new LineSeries
            {
                Values = new ChartValues<double>
                {
                    4,
                    5,
                    7,
                    8,
                    double.NaN,
                    5,
                    2,
                    8,
                    double.NaN,
                    6,
                    2
                }
            }
        };

        DataContext = this;
    }

    public SeriesCollection Series { get; set; }
```

xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding Series}">
    </lvc:CartesianChart> 
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly LiveCharts do not support missing points for `StepLineSeries`. Missing points feature exists only for `LineSeries`.